# How I can udate a document in mongodb without delete the information it contains?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am writing a program in Django using pymongo and I am using MongoDB database.
I have the following document:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("601cfa306f67d4f34bee6873"),
"user_id" : 2,
"timestamp" : ISODate("2021-02-05T08:56:32.432Z"),
"ips" : {
    "email" : "user1@gmail.com",
    "user_ip" : "127.0.0.1",
    "timestamp_id" : ISODate("2021-02-05T08:56:32.432Z")
},
"subprofile" : {
    "email" : "permission@gmail.com",
    "permission" : "post messages",
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2021-02-05T09:49:26.949Z")
}}
```

I want to update "subprofile" with the following code

```
def mongodb(id, email, permission):

mongo = MongoClient(port=27017)
db = mongo['engine']
collection = db['app_profile']
user = collection.find({'user_id': id})
#takes the _id and subpfofile

for u in user:
    user_id = u.get('_id')
    is_first= u.get('subprofile')
#checks if it is the first time that you use the databese    
if len(is_first) == 0:
#use the function write_permission to update the information for the first time                
    collection.update({'_id': user_id}, {'$set':{'subprofile': write_permission(email, permission)}}, 
 upsert=True)
#if subprofile contains some information add with write_permission other information without override 
the others
else:
    collection.update({'_id': user_id},{'$set':{'subprofile':write_permission(email, permission)})


def write_permission(email, permission):
    post = {
                "email": email,
                "permission": permission,
                "timestamp": datetime.datetime.now(),
            }
    return post
```

However, with `$set` I override the previous information!
I do not have a clue how to 'update' and do not override subprofile. If it would an array I would use $puch, but this is not the cases.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: See this updating the fields within an embedded document: [Update Examples](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-method-examples)

Comment: I've already read that part of the documentation, but it didn't help me. What I'm trying to do is add the three fields 'email', 'permission, e 'timestamp' to subprofile without change its content.I thought it was simple (and it sure is) but I got stuck. Thanks for your suggestion anyway